# Get TextBox Text value in a button

Tags: c#, css

I'm trying to get the value of `txt_MRP` in the codebehind but it keeps giving me

> The name "txt_MRP" doesn't exist in this current context

Why is this reference not available?  How can I get it?

(The button that I am pressing is `btn_add_to_cart_Click`)

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">

            <asp:DataList ID="DataList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <ul id="etalage">
                        <li>
                            <img id="Img1" class="etalage_thumb_image" runat="server" src='<%# Eval("Fotografia1") %>' />
                            <img id="Img2" class="etalage_source_image" runat="server" src='<%# Eval("Fotografia2") %>' />

                        </li>


                    </ul>
                    <br />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">

            <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >



                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div id="product_name_width">
                        <asp:Label ID="Product_nameLabel" runat="server" CssClass="product_name" Text='<%# Eval("Nombre") %>' />
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <span id="rs">₡</span><asp:Label ID="MRPLabel" CssClass="price" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Precio") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <span id="brand_name">Marca</span>
                    <asp:Label ID="BrandLabel" runat="server" CssClass="brand" Text='<%# Eval("Marca") %>' />
                    <br />

                    </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>  Cantidad </label>
                            <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" ID="txt_MRP" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>


                    </div>

                    <div id="buy_now_css" runat="server">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_add_to_cart" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Añadir al Carrito" OnClick="btn_add_to_cart_Click" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_buy_now" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="Comprar" OnClick="btn_buy_now_Click" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>

            <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <h2>Descripcion</h2>
                    <div id="Description_width">
                        <asp:Label ID="DetailLabel" CssClass="description" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Descripcion") %>' />
                    </div>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`txt_MRP` does not exist because it is in a `DataList` Control. It is only available inside the scope of the Control.
If you want to get the value you have to use another method.

Change the button event from `Onclick` to `OnCommand` and add a `CommandName` and set the `ItemIndex` as `CommandArgument`.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_add_to_cart" CommandName="addToCart" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Añadir al Carrito" OnCommand="btn_add_to_cart_Command"  />
```

And in code behind

```
protected void btn_add_to_cart_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //check the correct commandname
    if (e.CommandName == "addToCart")
    {
        //get the row number from the commandargument
        int itemIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        //find the texbox in the correct row with findcontrol
        TextBox textBox = DataList1.Items[itemIndex].FindControl("txt_MRP") as TextBox;

        //do stuff with the value
        Label1.Text = textBox.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the delegate or button.  For instance:

```
var button = new Button();
button.Click += new EventHandler("btnAddToCart");
```

You also may need a `CommandArgument`, to be able to send a specific value back.  But to actually register the click event would be like the above.